# MySQL: Finding most frequently occuring values in table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

Purchases:

```
item
001
003
002
001
002
004
003
001
002
```

Item:

```
id    |   name
001   |   Item 1
002   |   Item 2
003   |   Item 3
004   |   Item 4
```

I need to find the (multiple) items that occur most frequently in the purchases table, and output the name of the item. What should I have in my query?

**UPDATE** (using MAX and subqueries)

I can get the highest count by:

```
SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) AS "cnt" 
    FROM purchases LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = purchases.item 
    GROUP BY purchases.item) t;
```

Now I just need a way to get the names of the items that have that count.

Comment: mysql or sql? In mysql It is easy, sql would dissallow the same query, so it would be a little more tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.cnt, t.name FROM 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS "cnt", item.name 
  FROM purchases 
  LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = purchases.item 
  GROUP BY item.name) t
WHERE t.cnt = (SELECT MAX(t2.cnt) FROM 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS "cnt"
   FROM purchases 
   LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = purchases.item 
   GROUP BY item.name) t2
 )
```

I'm sure it must be a better way to do this, but this should work.

Comment: Not sure if I implemented it right, but comes up as Error: Invalid use of group function. The `WHERE` throws it off somehow

Comment: Mnnn try now? Do you have a sqlfiddle to test? I don't have access to a mysql right now.

Comment: Still no,  however when I remove the `WHERE` it does come up with the full list fine, just has all of them rather than just the max, so I think the problem is in the last line somehow.

I've never used an sqlfiddle, so I wouldn't know what to do

Comment: Check it now. It has to be a better way, but at least you'll get what you want.

Comment: Again comes up with a list of all of them, rather than just the max

Comment: There was a typo, MAX(t2.cnt) not MAX(t.cnt). In SQLite is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tested it, but try this.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS "count", item.id, item.name
FROM purchases
LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = purchase.item
GROUP BY item.id
ORDER BY count DESC
```

This is assuming the foreign key in `purchases` is `item` and not something like `item_id`.

Comment: that selects all of them, how do I limit it to just the most occuring ones (i.e. just 001 and 002 as they occur 3 times each)

Comment: do you mean that you are getting more than one result per item? That shouldn't happen because that's what the `GROUP BY` is for.

Comment: no, I mean it's returning the count of 003 and 004 too, when I just want the ones that occur most (001 and 002 - 3 times each)

Comment: if you want the top result just add `LIMIT 1` to the bottom of the query, I'm not actually sure how that works if both totals are the same though, don't think I've ever came across that before but you can change the `LIMIT` to whatever you wish.

Comment: I know the way to do it with `LIMIT`, I was hoping to do it without a fixed number

Comment: not sure, you could try looking into the `TOP` function

Comment: I'm wondering if there is a way to do it using `MAX`, maybe as a subquery

Comment: that might work too, I was trying to setup an sqlfiddle to experiment but it was stuck when I went to build the schema (http://sqlfiddle.com/).

Answer (score 0):

It's a easy and quick query:

```
SELECT b.name, count(a.item) as total, 
FROM purchases a 
LEFT JOIN item b ON  a.item = b.id
GROUP BY b.name
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: This one confuses me a little. Firstly you just have `Select`  `From`, with nothing selected. Secondly where does b come from?