# MySQL: Refine answer to Finding most frequently occuring values in table

Tags: mysql

Was posted yesterday at:

[MySQL: Finding most frequently occuring values in table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856205/mysql-finding-most-frequently-occuring-values-in-table)

But was wondering if there is a way to refine the answer, as you shouldn't have to repeat the code at the end to get the `MAX(COUNT)`

**Question**

I have two tables:

Purchases:

```
item
001
003
002
001
002
004
003
001
002
```

Item:

```
id    |   name
001   |   Item 1
002   |   Item 2
003   |   Item 3
004   |   Item 4
```

Expected output:

```
item     name
001      Item 1
002      Item 2
```

I need to find the (multiple) items that occur most frequently in the purchases table, and output the name of the item. What should I have in my query?

**Answer I have so far**

```
SELECT t.cnt, t.name FROM 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS "cnt", item.name 
  FROM purchases 
  LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = purchases.item 
  GROUP BY item.name) t
WHERE t.cnt = (SELECT MAX(t2.cnt) FROM 
 (SELECT COUNT(*) AS "cnt"
   FROM purchases 
   LEFT JOIN item ON item.id = purchases.item 
   GROUP BY item.name) t2
 )
```

Comment: You could have multiple items appearing many times in the purchase table. So while listing do you restrict to a certain number ? Or what would be the expected result from the given example data.

Comment: Always provide expected output for the sample data so we can understand.

Comment: I'd like to output the name of the items that appear most frequently (i.e. 001 and 002 as they appear 3 times each, and not 003 or 004)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first obtain the maximal count, then use that to filter for matching items:

```
SELECT   i.*
FROM     purchases p
    JOIN item i ON i.id = p.item
GROUP BY i.id
HAVING   COUNT(*) = (
           SELECT   COUNT(*)
           FROM     purchases
           GROUP BY item
           ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
           LIMIT    1
         )
```

Note that this query relies on `id` being the PK of (or at very least unique within) your `item` table, for two reasons:

1. It ensures that the `JOIN` does not adversely affect the `COUNT(*)` in the outer query; and
2. It enables you to determinately select `*` from `item` despite the grouping operation (other RDBMS platforms wouldn't allow this, but would require you to group on every non-aggregated output column—but MySQL offers this "feature" as a performance improvement).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT I.`id` AS id, COUNT(I.`id`) AS `id_count`, P.`name` AS name
FROM `item` I
JOIN `purchases` P
ON I.`id` = P.`id`
ORDER BY COUNT(I.`id`) DESC
GROUP BY I.`id`
```

Expected Output:

```
|-------|-------------|--------------------|
|   id  | id_count    |     name          |
|-------|-------------|-------------------|
| 101   |     5       |     Item 1        |
| 102   |     6       |     Item 2        |
| 103   |     8       |     Item 3        |
| 104   |     12      |     Item 4        |
...
|------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Still returns all the results (001, 002, 003, 004) Where I just want the ones with the highest `COUNT` (001, 002)

Comment: yes but that's not what I want, check expected output above, only 001 and 002 as they appear the most frequently (3 times)

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this could work. You can using 'having' and 'order by' to get top results.

```
SELECT count(p.item), i.name
FROM purchases p, item i
WHERE p.item = i.id
GROUP BY p.item HAVING count(p.item) > 1
ORDER BY count(p.item) DESC;
```

Optionally you could add 'LIMIT 1' to the end.

Comment: This returns 003 as well, which appears twice. I only want the ones that occur most frequently, and ideally not using a fixed number like > 1.